# Liferay ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-16] is not a valid include

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, liferay

I'm struggling with the doView() method and initializing parameters from the portlet.xml. What I've been trying so far, is to just redirect to another view when I click a button, or a link. For that, I created two JSP:

view.jsp
vista2.jsp

I define them in portlet.xml:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>res-prot</portlet-name>
    <display-name>Res Prot</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.test.ResProt</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>view-jsp</name>
        <value>html/resprot/view.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <name>vista2-jsp</name>
        <value>/vista2.jsp</value>
    </init-param>   
    (...)
```

Then, I initialize them in the init() method:

```
String viewJSP;
String vista2JSP;

public void init() throws PortletException {
    viewJSP = getInitParameter("view-jsp");
    vista2JSP = getInitParameter("vista2-jsp");
}
```

Finally, I call to the doView() method, which calls the viewJSP if a parameter "navegacion" is empty:

```
@Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        String destino = viewJSP;

        try {
            // we redirect only if "navegacion" is sent from the jsp
            if (renderRequest.getParameter("navegacion") != null){
                if(renderRequest.getParameter("navegacion").equalsIgnoreCase("vista2JSP")){
                    destino = vista2JSP;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("DESTINO: "+destino);
            include(destino, renderRequest, renderResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Then, in the vista2.jsp I just use a renderURL to do that call, but I don't even get there. I get this error and the portlet shows empty:

> 09:21:41,402 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-16][MVCPortlet:357]
>   html/resprot/view.jsp is not a valid include

This is how this dirty project is organized (remember that this is only for testing purposes):

[image]

What's failing here?

EDIT:

If I begin the route by "/", it throws a different error:

> DESTINO: /html/resprot/view.jsp java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.isValidPath(LiferayPortlet.java:425)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.checkPath(LiferayPortlet.java:193)
>     at
>   com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:360)
>     at
>   com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:378)
>     at com.test.ResProt.doView(ResProt.java:52)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:235)
>     at
>   com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:314)
>     at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:262)     at
>   com.test.ResProt.render(ResProt.java:35)  at
>   com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:583)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:656)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:362)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1239)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:638)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:125)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.access$4(PortletRenderer.java:107)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:180)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:1)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.executor.CopyThreadLocalCallable.call(CopyThreadLocalCallable.java:69)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

EDIT 2: If I move "view.jsp" to the root folder, keeps throwing the same error:

> DESTINO: /view.jsp java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.isValidPath(LiferayPortlet.java:425)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.checkPath(LiferayPortlet.java:193)
>     at
>   com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:360)
>     at
>   com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:378)
>     at com.test.ResProt.doView(ResProt.java:52)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:235)
>     at
>   com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:314)
>     at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:262)     at
>   com.test.ResProt.render(ResProt.java:35)  at
>   com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:583)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:656)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:362)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1239)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:638)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:125)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.access$4(PortletRenderer.java:107)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:180)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:1)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.executor.CopyThreadLocalCallable.call(CopyThreadLocalCallable.java:69)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
<value>html/resprot/view.jsp</value>
```

By

```
<value>/html/resprot/view.jsp</value>
```

Comment: It fails equally. I had tried it what way, but in that case, I get many other errors.

Comment: Yes, let me get the error log, I'll paste it here in a moment

Comment: There you have it, in the main question.

Comment: Can you try to replace your folder name "html" by "html2"? Indeed there is already a folder call html for intern Liferay fonctionnality

Comment: I moved my "view.jsp" to the root web folder, but it keeps throwing an error. Check it in the main question, please

Comment: Don't move "view.jsp" in the ROOT webapp. Just change <value>/html/resport/view.jsp" to <value>/html2/resport/view.jsp" and rename the directory in your project. Can you also check if the jsp is in the right place in the final war.

Comment: Can you add the content of view.jsp please ?